# I am having difficulty embedding a video inside an image

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to embed a video inside an image and have been having a really hard time doing so. You can see an example of where I am at up to this point? Is there an easier way to do this by adding padding, margins or an additional div?

Here is my code:

```css
div.tv-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 67.5%;
  height: 0;
}

div.tv-wrapper iframe {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://garrandwebsite.staging.wpengine.com/wp-
 content/uploads/2017/12/TV-Background-Image.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  padding: 6.3% 12.8% 20.7% 12.8%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="tv-wrapper"><iframe class="sproutvideo-player" src="//videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/489adcb51e1debcdc0/e0d9daac7a1a9b30?
    bigPlayButton=false&amp;showControls=false" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you not supposed the have quotations around your image url?

Comment: background: url("whatever");

Comment: I add the quotations but unfortunately that didn't resolve the issue. Is there an easy way to position and move the video iframe inside the div? Everytime I change the left padding, the entire iframe size changes.

Comment: I’d probably simply use absolute positioning, instead of trying to “nudge” this in place from all four directions using padding. (You will need an additional container for that though, because what you have here relies on the padding-bottom spanning up the container to get the iframe its correct size to begin with.)

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I already have a "container" in place so I am wonder if I could utilize that. Any chance you have sample code or could point me in the right direction for how I could do this using absolute positioning? This is a new approach for me. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @StewartM Working on it

Comment: Thank you @Highdef. I look forward to seeing what you are able to come up with!

Comment: I've got it working alright but for some reason the video isn't being responsive for larger dimensions. It's stuck to its original size. Does that work for you?

Comment: I have not had that issue. I am wondering if we could use an iFrame with a responsive video.<div style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:56.25%"><iframe class='sproutvideo-player' src='//videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/489adcb51e1debcdc0/e0d9daac7a1a9b30' style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

Answer (score 0):

Finally devised a solution using vw (view-width) instead of % to solve the responsive issue. Hope, this helps. :)

```css
.tv-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-left:2%;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: url("http://garrandwebsite.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/TV-Background-Image.jpg");
  width: 100vw;
  height: 56.5vw;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

iframe {
  height: 73%;
  width: 71%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="tv-wrapper">
        <iframe class="sproutvideo-player" src="//videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/489adcb51e1debcdc0/e0d9daac7a1a9b30?
bigPlayButton=false&amp;showControls=false" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this isn't work exactly as I had hoped it would but certainly helpful nonetheless. What we are really trying to achieve is the following: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HDquA2pGlgbDPTVec0pcCde_xMnMdYkl/view

Comment: @StewartM I tried to tweak it around everyway I knew, but the video won't just fit and be responsive in relation to the image.

Comment: I have run into a similar issue. I wonder if using a different video would work. I am also wondering if the dimensions of the container should be identical to the dimensions of the video. I will keep playing around, I wish there was an easier way to accomplish this. I am surprised there aren't more templates out there.

Comment: @StewartM I know, I have seen other people code up something like this but they always keep the container size fixed, I guess its a mess to deal it haha :) Anyways, if my solution helped, you can mark it. Cheers

Comment: @StewartM I devised a solution for this problem finally :) Rate and accept if it helps. Cheers